# How to insert count() value when using Django to develop Web front end

Tags: python, html, django, frontend, backend

I'm developing a web visual board using Django.

Here is the part of html that I want to insert database's values into.

```
    <tbody>
        {% for obj in data_list %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ obj.id }}</th>
            <th>{{ obj.major }}</th>
            <th>{{ obj.name }}</th>
            <th>{{ obj.age }}</th>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

As you can see, this can help me to insert data: id, major, name and age.
But now I want to insert values that use count() function in MySQL, which is fuzzy lookup:
    `SELECT COUNT(Issue_date) AS NumberOfProducts FROM first_project.itsec_china WHERE Issue_date like '2022%';`

Basically, I want to insert the number of those items issued in year 2022.
How can I change my code, for example, this part:
    `{{ obj.age }}`

Below is what is in my view.py:

```
    def orm(request):
        # Insert data to database
        # itsec_china.objects.create(cerfitied_product='Game Security App',
        #                      company = 'riot',
        #                      cerfitication_number = 'xxx111',
        #                      certification_date = 20220214,
        #                      validation_date = 20240214)
        TryCC.objects.create(name='Bruce',
                             major='CS',
                             age= 27)
        data_list = TryCC.objects.all()
    
        return render(request, 'cc_list.html', {'data_list': data_list})
```

I'm trying to find someone have the knowledge to give me the answer or a place to study about it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please share with us the view file? What does the view look like?

Comment: I upload my view file : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the following line under your view file

```
count = itsec_china.objects.filter(Issue_date__startswith='2022').count()

....
return render(request, 'cc_list.html', {'data_list': data_list, 'count': count})
```

and then your template should look like

```
<tbody>
    {% for obj in data_list %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{ obj.id }}</th>
        <th>{{ obj.major }}</th>
        <th>{{ obj.name }}</th>
        <th>{{ obj.age }}</th>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tr>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>{{ count }}</th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In a nutshell, the `filter` method is used to get the count of items issued in 2022. The `Issue_date__startswith` lookup is used to filter the rows where the Issue_date field starts with '2022'. The `count` method is then used to count the number of rows that match the filter.